# Does anything change on getGasPrice( ) in Web3js after EIP-1559?

Tags: web3js, gas, gas-price

Using getGasPrice in web3js returns the last few blocks median gas price. After EIP-1559, the fees system is divided into Base + Tip.

My question is, what is returned using getGasPrice after EIP1559? Is it the total average Base+Tip value or just one or the other?

Comment: I'm actually wondering the same thing. I have an application that's been running for some time now fine using the `eth.getGasPrice()` function. Now suddenly I'm starting to see the following errors: max fee per gas less than block base fee: address {address}, maxFeePerGas: 5000000000 baseFee: 27318189081 (supplied gas 4014405)

Comment: Did you try updating to the newer versions of web3js? It seems that they've made it compatible now

Comment: I have tried. Unfortunately, there's an outstanding bug with web3 and ganache-cli that prevents me from using it. In case anyone is curious about the bug: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/4454

Answer (score 0):

> what is returned using getGasPrice after EIP-1559 ? Is it the total average Base+Tip value or just one or the other?

Something similar to pre [EIP-1559](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1559) for backward compatibility : The base fee + a gas tip estimation, this value is directly usable for legacy transactions.

You can see the go-ethereum implementation of the RPC [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/f01e2fab07a20a4be5bedde45a366cfe89f07cd4/internal/ethapi/api.go#L64) where the base fee is explicitely added to a gasTipCap estimation.

You can also see it for yourself by running the following web3 code on mainnet:

```
const gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(gasPrice, "Gwei"));

// Displays : 30.38 at the time of writing
// Which at block 14448993 is around 25 Gwei of base fee + 5 Gwei of gas tip cap.
```

I hope that answers your question.

---

For the error mentioned in the comments : given the code I linked, you *may* encounter an error as metioned in the comments if the current header cannot be accessed by your provider for any reason :

```
if head := s.b.CurrentHeader(); head.BaseFee != nil {
        tipcap.Add(tipcap, head.BaseFee)
    }
```

As it would bypass the addition of the baseFee and probably result in a gasPrice lower than the baseFee itself leading to the rejection of your tx. That's just an idea.